# Using Fluent Validation how can I check that two properties in an object both can't have a value?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I want to validate two properties (`MyProperty1`, `MyProperty2`) in a class. These properties can both be null. They both have separate validation rules but they cannot both have a value set.

```
public MyObject 
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to avoid writing something like this

```
            When(
            c => c.MyProperty1 != null && c.MyProperty2 != null,
            () =>
                this.RuleFor(r => r.MyProperty1 )
                    .Null()
                    .WithMessage("MyProperty1 must be null when MyProperty2 has value"));
```

Comment: If you want to minimize your code and be more straightforward, maybe you could try to pass the whole object to the custom validation and separate this null check in a separate method. 
f.e.: `RuleFor(c => c).Must(myObject => PropertiesCheckMethod(myObject.MyProperty1 , myObject.MyProperty2)).WithMessage("Your error");`

Comment: Does the following match your needs? `RuleFor(o => o.MyProperty1).Null().When(o => o.MyProperty2 != null); RuleFor(o => o.MyProperty2).Null().When(o => o.MyProperty1 != null);`. It's two lines but I find it pretty easy to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will achieve that and keeps the fluent readability.

```
RuleFor(o => o.MyProperty1)
    .Null()
    .When(o => o.MyProperty2 != null)
    .WithMessage("MyProperty1 must be null when MyProperty2 has value");

RuleFor(o => o.MyProperty2)
    .Null()
    .When(o => o.MyProperty1 != null)
    .WithMessage("MyProperty2 must be null when MyProperty1 has value");
```